# JQuery in Wordpress update WPFORMs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wpforms

I am building a website in Wordpress and I'm trying to have a form populate data based on a button press.
I am using the headers and footers plugin and can validate the "script" is loading on the page.
However nothing seems to happen and I don't know where to begin.

I am using the Headers and Footers Plugin to add the Script.
I am using WPFORM,I have setup the classes
Just mildly lost now

Button has the class Custom.
WPFORM Field has the Class CompanyName

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Button click event
  jQuery('#Custom').click(function() {
    jQuery('#CompanyName').val('Hello');
  });
});
</script>
```

Script on the Page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Yny.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by changing the Jquery
I added the "Click" to validate the Jquery was loading correctly which will display in the developer tab under console

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Button click event
  jQuery('.custom').click(function() {
    jQuery('#wpforms-2453-field_2').val('Hello');
  });
});
</script>
```